# Changing variable output name in glm

Tags: r

I have built a function `f` that runs an anova given an `x` and `y` variable. I used NSE to make the function easier to use. Here is an example that is replicable and isolates the problem:

```
library(carData)

df <- carData::Salaries


f <- function(x,y, data){
  x <- ensym(x)
  y <- ensym(y)
  m <- aov(glm(data[[y]] ~  data[[x]], family='gaussian',data=data))
  print(summary(m))
}
```

output:

```
> f(rank, salary, df )
             Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
data[[x]]     2 1.432e+11 7.162e+10   128.2 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   394 2.201e+11 5.586e+08                   
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The function works, great! But the output shows the variable name as `data[[x]]`. I would like to change this variable name that matches the input.

I have converted `x` to a character like:

```
x_string <- as.character(x)
```

But I don't know where in `glm` I can change the variable name.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten your user defined function a bit and use `substitute(y ~ x)`:

```
f <- function(x, y, data){
  summary(aov(glm(substitute(y ~  x), family = 'gaussian', data = data)))
}

f(rank, salary, df)

#              Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
# rank          2 1.432e+11 7.162e+10   128.2 <2e-16 ***
# Residuals   394 2.201e+11 5.586e+08                   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R is perfectly capable of NSE too, there is no need for `ensym` in this case. Get the variables as character strings with a `deparse(substitute(.))` trick and put the regression formula terms together with base function [`reformulate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html).

Also, the function's return value is (always)  the return value of the last instruction, in this case `print`. And if auto print is enabled, the default, there is no need to call it explicitly, `summary` alone will do the job.

```r
df <- carData::Salaries

f <- function(x,y, data){
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y <- deparse(substitute(y))
  fmla <- reformulate(x, y)
  m <- aov(glm(fmla, family='gaussian',data=data))
  summary(m)
}

f(rank, salary, df)
#>              Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
#> rank          2 1.432e+11 7.162e+10   128.2 <2e-16 ***
#> Residuals   394 2.201e+11 5.586e+08                   
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>